# Where should != operator be defined in a class hierarchy?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, comparison-operators

Here is a very simple class hierarchy:

```
class A
{
public:
    A( int _a ) : a( _a ) {}

    virtual bool operator==( const A& right ) const
    {
        return a == right.a;
    }

    virtual bool operator!=( const A& right ) const
    {
        return !( *this == right );
    }

    int a;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B( int _a, int _b ) : A( _a ), b( _b ) {}

    virtual bool operator==( const B& right ) const
    {
        return A::operator==( right ) && b == right.b;
    }

    int b;
};
```

As you can see, operator != is defined in the base class. Because I'm very lazy, I don't want to duplicate such a simple code in all the derived classes.

Unfortunatley, with this code:

```
A a4(4), a5(5), a4bis(4);
assert( a4 == a4bis );
assert( a4 != a5 );

B b1(4,5), b2(4,6);
assert( !(b1 == b2) );
assert( b1 != b2 ); // fails because B::operator== is not called!
```

`b1 != b2` returns false, because it executes `A::operator!=` which calls then `A::operator==` rather than `B::operator==` (even if the operator is virtual, as derived class version parameter is different, they are not linked in the vtable).

So what's the best way to adress != operator in a generic way for a class hierarchy?

One solution is to repeat it in each class, `B` would then have:

```
virtual bool operator!=( const B& right ) const
{
    return !( *this == right );
}
```

But that's a pain when you have many classes....I have 30....

Another solution would be to have a generic template approach:

```
template <class T>
bool operator!=( const T& left, const T& right )
{
    return !( left == right );
}
```

But this bypasses any `!=` operator defined by any class....so it may be risky if one declared it differently (or if one declared a `==` itself calling `!=`, it would end up with an infinite loop...). So I feel this solution being very unsafe....except if we can limit the template to be used for all classes derived from the top-level class of our hierarchy (`A` in my example)....but I don't think this is doable at all.

Note: I'm not using C++11 yet...sorry about that.

Comment: Moreover, currently, `A(42) == B(42, 0)` as you compare only the `A` part...

Comment: For clarity and to ensure that A continues to work independently (if you don't want it to, you don't need to derive B from it), implement != for A, B, C, D and whatever you have in your hierarchy.  Again if you don't need them, why do you need to derive at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this ?

```
class A {
  protected :
    virtual bool equals(const A& right) const {
      return (a == right.a);
    }

  public :
    A(int _a) : a(_a) { }

    bool operator==(const A& right) const {
      return this->equals(right);
    }
    bool operator!=(const A& right) const {
      return !(this->equals(right));
    }

    int a;
};

class B : public A {
  protected :
    virtual bool equals(const A& right) const {
      if (const B* bp = dynamic_cast<const B*>(&right)) {
        return A::equals(right) && (b == bp->b);
      }
      return false;
    }

  public :
    B(int _a, int _b) : A(_a), b(_b) { }

    int b;
};
```

Move the comparison logic to a separate (virtual) function `equals`, and call that function from the `operator==` and `operator!=` defined in the base class.

The operators don't need to be re-defined in the derived classes. To change the comparison in a derived class, simply override `equals`.

Note that the `dynamic_cast` in the code above is used to ensure that the runtime type is a valid type for performing the comparison. Ie. for `B::equals`, it's used to ensure that `right` is a `B` - this is necessary because otherwise `right` would not have a `b` member.

Comment: With that you have `B(42, 0) != A(42)` but still `A(42) == B(42, 0)`. It would require multiple dispatch.

Comment: Can you say some more words about your approach? Thanks :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 : that is a choice you make (and I copied the behavior from the OP). If you want the equality operators to be commutative, then double dispatch (as you suggest) can indeed help.

Comment: Thanks! Having a third `equals` function each class can override is a nice way to fix my problem.

Comment: ...according this *double dispatch* thing: I have a bad feeling about an *answer* without any warning about it - the *question* is about **being different (`!=`)** in a **hierarchy**.

Comment: @jpo38 you obviously have no problem with the antinomy `b != a && a == b` mentioned by [Jarod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264849/where-should-operator-be-defined-in-a-class-hierarchy/31265515#comment50525926_31265515)?

Comment: @Wolf : I guess I don't see the reason for a warning, since the OP doesn't indicate a concern about commutativity when comparing different types (and there's nothing wrong with that - it's a choice). In any case, such warnings have been added in several comments, so they are there for those that need them.

Comment: You are right: `assert( b1 != b2 ); // fails because B::operator== is not called!` was the actual problem and your answer solved it.

Comment: For my concern, this answers the question. I did not consider operator commutativity in my OP...

Comment: The way my class hierarchy is made and used ends up obnly comparing A vs A or B vs B objects (as shown in the example). Never A vs B. So that's not a problem for me.

Answer (score 6):

Your function in `B`...

```
virtual bool operator==( const B& right ) const
```

...does *not* override the function in `A`...

```
virtual bool operator==( const A& right ) const
```

...because the argument types differ.  (Differences are only allowed for covariant return types.)

If you correct this, you'll then be able to choose how to compare `B` objects to other `A` and `A`-derived objects, e.g. perhaps:

```
bool operator==( const A& right ) const override
{
    if (A::operator==( right ))
        if (typeid(*this) == typeid(right))
            return b == static_cast<const B&>(right).b;
    return false;
}
```

Note that using the `typeid` comparison above means only `B` objects will compare equal: any `B` will compare unequal to any `B`-derived object.  This may or may not be what you want.

With an implementation for `B::operator==`, the existing `!=` implementation will properly wrap `operator==`.  As Jarod42 observes, your `A::operator==` isn't robust in that when the left-hand-side value is an `A` only the `A` slice of the right-hand-side object will be compared... you might prefer:

```
virtual bool operator==(const A& right) const
{
    return a == right.a && typeid(*this) == typeid(right);
}
```

This has the same issues as the `B::operator==` above: e.g. an `A` would compare un-equal to a derived object that didn't introduce further data members.

Comment: Are those dynamic_cast and typeid really safe (even when using template classes, because my class hirerachy has templates....)?

Comment: @jpo38:they're safe, yes... distinct RTTI/typeinfo objects will be created for each template instantiation.

Comment: Thanks. Your code works welI, but I prefer `Sander De Dycker` solution because I prefer derived class (B) to cast a A object as B rather than having the parent class (A) to cast to do the casting as you proposed (it may lead to a code difficult to read if the class hierarchy is huge).

Comment: @jpo38: I've not looked at his code to compare, but on the specific criteria you mention - *"rather than having the parent class (A) to cast to do the casting as you proposed"* - I didn't propose that at all... the *only* cast above is within `B::operator==` where it casts other `B` objects to `B&` to access their `b` member.  Maybe you mistook that code for being `A::operator==` - the `override` shows it's for `B`.

Comment: OK, you're absolutely right, sorry about that. I voted for both of you guys anyway ;-). Thanks!